# where is Neo4j::Session in the neo4j-core gem?

Tags: ruby, neo4j, jruby, require

I am looking up the documentation here at :
https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j-core

I want to use the session feature as :

```
session = Neo4j::Session.open(:server_db, "http://localhost:7474")
```

I have the following gems installed as told by `gem list` on jruby-1.7.4

```
neo4j-community (1.9.M05 java)
neo4j-core (2.3.0 java)
neo4j-cypher (1.0.2)
```

I cannot use Neo4j::Session as I always get an error:

```
NameError:
       uninitialized constant Neo4j::Session
```

Opening an irb session and requiring neo4j-core and inspecting shows me this :

[image]

The Session module is nowhere to be found. Where am I missing out on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read documentation for v3.0, but use stable gem v2.3.0